# Javascript parentheses Coloring.

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm trying to get the [Better Rainbow Parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim) working on Javascript files. I use the [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) and [vim-javascript-syntax](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax) for syntax, but I can't seem to get the parentheses to highlight.

I'm using the following:

```
au VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadRound
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadSquare
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadBraces
```

Comment: Is vim giving you any errors, are you sure your .vimrc is being loaded? Have you tried calling :RainbowParenthesesToggle from inside a buffer?

Comment: Looks like it does something - it changes the color of all the parentheses the same though, instead of rainbow. Would that be an issue with the javascript syntax highlighter?

Comment: The colors only change at different nested levels if they are on the same level they will not change.

Comment: If I have something like `rainbow(test(), colors());` there should be three different colors, but I only see one.

Comment: That should actually only give you two color since test and colors would be on the same level of nesting. I see two different shades of red when using your example. Can you add a screenshot to your question.